# Linux - delete lines containing ":\r\n"

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I'm looking for a command to delete lines where ":\r\n" is found. For example from:

```
test1:
test2:true
tool3:
tool4:false
```

to:

```
test2:true
tool4:false
```

I'm not used to sed very much I tried:

`sed '/:\r\n/d'` doesn't work

`sed '/test1/d'` works for this line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to match the newline character, you could match the EOL character, represented by `$`:

```bash
sed '/:$/d' file.txt
```

Comment: It does what I wanted indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can print all lines that have a `:` followed with any char:

```bash
sed -n '/:./p' file.txt
```

Here, `-n` suppresses default line output, `:.` matches a colon followed with any one char, and `p` prints the line matched.

It is even more elegant with `awk`:

```bash
awk '/:./' file.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/UMBiBZ):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='test1:
test2:true
tool3:
tool4:false'
sed -n '/:./p' <<< "$s"
awk '/:./' <<< "$s"
```

Both output:

```
test2:true
tool4:false
```